# Why weren't there clone naval officers at the end of Revenge of the Sith?

Tags: star-wars

In *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*, it was revealed that most of the officers of the Republic Navy were clones.

[image]

If so, then why weren't there any at the end of *Revenge of the Sith* on the bridge of the star destroyer? Were the clones already phased out this quickly, or is there a different reason?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Palpatine might have disliked clones

The Empire had a codified policy of xenophobia. Wookiees and Twi’leks were often enslaved, for example. This was definitely something promoted by the Emperor himself, and not merely the prevailing attitude:

> Palpatine and his propaganda machine worked to drive that nail of
> bigotry deeper by demonstrating how the old Jedi thugs and the
> scumfroth rebels consisted of many more nonhumans than humans. You
> could trust a human, the Empire said; aliens would always betray you.
>
> <sub>*Star Wars: Aftermath: Life Debt*</sub>

It is difficult to say how much Palpatine bought into this. He was a hypocrite at best: his former apprentice Darth Maul was a Zabrak, for example. Nonetheless, it seems likely that Palpatine, being a human himself, supremely arrogant, and indeed the source of much of the Empire’s propaganda, might have believed nonhumans to be inferior.

If this were the case (or even if were not), it would not be extraordinary for him to have a similar attitude toward clones.  They had short lifespans, were blindly obedient, and (according to now-Legends material) were unable to effectively wield the power of the Dark Side: all things that Palpatine was likely to despise.

The Star Destroyer that we see at the end is probably not an ordinary ship. It is transporting Palpatine and Vader to view the Death Star construction. As such, it may be a flagship or other vessel important to Palpatine. **In any case, if Palpatine believed clones to be inferior, his first step would probably be ensuring that the important ships had no clones among their officers.**

Comment: This answer is close to the one I was looking for. I am aware that Palpatine hated clones, but I am also aware that they continued to use clones for a few weeks after the events of Revenge of the Sith. The Kanan: The Last Padawan comic is my source for that. Many clones went after the Padawan Caleb Dume for weeks until he was presumed dead.

Comment: Where is it stated that Palpatine hated clones?

Comment: @Thomas - I don’t think it is (unless Donatello knows something I don’t).  I was suggesting that there is good reason to think he would have looked down on clones.

Comment: I believe that in one of the Servants of the Empire books, Brendol Hux says that Palpatine secretly found the clones to be inferior beings. However, he did use clones for a few weeks after the Clone Wars (see my previous comment).

Answer (score 1):

Clones continued to be used for quite some time after Order 66, according to both Disney and Legend canon, however as has begun to be shown with the Bad Batch series the clones were compromised by the execution of Order 66 (losing much of the jedi & kaminoan encouraged independence) and becoming ironically enough both more aggressive and "robotic" in behaviour.

Whilst the films and TV series have focussed on the droids and clones during the Clone Wars, much of the fighting was actually done by system defence forces with the clones being used primarily as assault/elite forces for key targets - whilst the droids were likewise used to supplement local forces and target key locations of importance for Count Dooku and his true master. When the war ended and the Republic became the Empire most of these local militaries were subsumed into the Imperial military bringing with them their non-clone officer corp.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You seem to be focusing on the clone troopers; the question was about navy officers who were clones.  Even if system defense forces were joined into the Imperial navy, that doesn't explain what happened to the existing clone officers who were already deployed to the major capital ships.