# Does the Imperial pro-human stance exist in Disney canon?

Tags: star-wars

I had always associated the Galactic Empire, almost out of reflex, with their notorious anti-alien, human-supremacist policy. However, now that I think about it, I can't recall any current-canon source affirming that this is not a Legends-only thing.

Does anyone have a source to confirm if this policy exists in the canon Empire as well?

Answer (score 5):

### Probably

An [answer to another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/139621/31936) provides a quote from a canon novel which suggests that the Empire is anti-alien:

> Palpatine and his propaganda machine worked to drive that nail of
> bigotry deeper by demonstrating how the old Jedi thugs and the
> scumfroth rebels consisted of many more nonhumans than humans. You
> could trust a human, the Empire said; aliens would always betray you.
>
> <sub>*Star Wars: Aftermath: Life Debt*</sub>

Furthermore, Wookieepedia's article on [xenophobia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Xenophobia) cites [*Star Wars Propaganda: A History of Persuasive Art in the Galaxy*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Propaganda:_A_History_of_Persuasive_Art_in_the_Galaxy) in stating that the Empire classified several non-human species (such as Wookiees) as "non-sentient". The Empire also enslaved several non-human species, such as the Wookiees and Mon Calamari, though there are non-xenophobic reasons for the Empire to do this (the Wookiees' strength makes them useful for hard labor, and the Mon Calamari proved a particularly rebellious species).

Also, the Rebel Alliance accused the Empire of an anti-alien policy in its [Declaration of Rebellion](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Declaration_of_Rebellion):

> You have instituted a policy of blatant racism and genocide against the nonhuman peoples of the Galaxy.

While the Declaration of Rebellion specifically accuses the Empire of instituting an anti-alien *policy*, the Rebels might have been lying and/or stretching the truth in their declaration.

Finally, it's worth mentioning that humans also seem to be disproportionately represented among Imperial officers (though there are also some high-ranking non-humans, such as [Mas Amedda](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mas_Amedda)).

That said, I'm unaware of a *specific* Imperial law or policy which states that humans are superior than non-humans and/or which promotes discrimination against non-humans.

Comment: Well, I should point out that I used the word "policy" loosely. I don't mean black & white legislation, more like the Imperial government's...culture/disposition? I struggle to find the right word. Anyway, one opinion I had was that the rank-and-file were exclusively human as a legacy from the GAR, as well as in keeping with the Imperial policy towards suppressing individuals from standing out. Among the officer corps though...we see such a small sample size in the media, so who knows if there are other alien officers like Thrawn (although not as brilliant enough to ever be mentioned)?